# Identify a movie with kids playing Final Fantasy VIII

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

The movie was released between 1998-2001, but all I can remember of it is a single scene, two naked women randomly walk into a house and past two kids playing Final Fantasy VIII on a PlayStation. I believe it was a comedy movie.

And specifically, in-game, it was Quistis and Squall fighting a T-Rexaur in the Balamb Garden Training Center.

Comment: Sounds like you clearly remembered the wrong details of the movie. :D According to Wikipedia, FF8 has been released in 1999, so I guess you yould move/shorten the possible timeframe by at least one year.

Comment: Hi. Just a reminder: if my post answered your question, please remember to click "Accept". Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't seen this question in nearly three years. Apologies, I just accepted. And yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie myself, but I've heard of a scene that sounds somewhat similar in [Charlie's Angels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie%27s_Angels_%28film%29).

Comment: I believe that it does seem like a match. And I back you up with the video of the scene: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGSOJlW59wY

Comment: Now if I was playing FFVII I might not have looked up. But FFVIII? Blech

Comment: It was Charlie's angels. I freaked, it was my favorite game lol